# Raspi 2 v1.1 freezes randomly

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, power-supply

I set up my old Raspi2 v1.1 a few days ago, but its behaving strange.

It freezes / hangs up after some time.

Things I've tried so far:

- Swapped out my sdcard for a different one
- Copied the os to an usb drive and modified the boot process accordingly
- Swapped usb cord & power supply.

Some outputs:

```
pi@rainbowrack:~ $ vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=53.5'C

pi@rainbowrack:~ $ vcgencmd measure_volts
volt=1.3625V

pi@rainbowrack:~ $ vcgencmd get_throttled
throttled=0x0
```

I'm currently using the wall plug that came with my iPad for power delivery, which was listed somewhere as "working".

Comment: Are you using the latest Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop, fully updated?

Comment: @CoderMike Yes, I've downloaded the latest Raspberry Pi Image (v1.4) and prepared a fresh sdcard with `Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Release: 2020-08-20`. It is now freezing regardless of workload.

Comment: *I'm currently using the wall plug that came with my iPad for power delivery, which was listed somewhere as "working".* - Thats not a power supply its a charger.  Try a real power supply.